# Java stream filter sum of values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class called `MonitoredData` with which describes an activity, its starting time and ending time. The attributes are `activityLabel`, `startTime`, `endTime`. I have to group and filter these activities, using streams, the activities which have the total duration of more than 10 hours. I managed to make the sum of durations and group them according to the activity using this:

```
Map<String, Long> map4 = new HashMap<String, Long>();

map4 = data.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MonitoredData::getActivity, 
            Collectors.summingLong(MonitoredData::getDuration)
        )
    ); //getDuration returns end Time - startTime in milliseconds
```

But I haven't managed to add a filter. I tried using:

```
.filter(Collectors.summingLong(MonitoredData::getDuration) > whatever)
```

but obviously it doesn't work. How can I solve this in order to make it return a `Map<String, Long>`?

Comment: Add the `.filter` before the `collect` operation?

Comment: You should first map `obj -> (obj, sumDuration)` and then apply the filter on the resulting object.

Comment: I'm on phone, maybe your question is more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097658/how-to-send-parameters-to-a-reference-method-in-a-stream-java-8/44098230#44098230)/[that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086903/how-to-add-datetime-values-in-a-streamjava/44087302#44087302) excepts the filtering. You can completing yours by grouing/merging and then filtering.

Comment: Just a side note: don’t initialize variables with objects you never use. The `= new HashMap<String, Long>()` in your code is somewere between misleading and nonsensical. The resulting value of `map4` will be whatever `collect` returned, due to your assignment, initializing it with a `HashMap` before, has no influence on the result.

Answer (score 6):

I would first do as you've already done: I'd collect the stream of `MonitoredData` instances to a map, grouping by activity and summing the duration of each activity in each value:

```
Map<String, Long> map4 = data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MonitoredData::getActivity, 
        HashMap::new,
        Collectors.summingLong(MonitoredData::getDuration)));
```

The nuance is that I'm using the [overloaded version of `Collectors.groupingBy` that accepts a factory for the map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-), because in the next step I want to remove the entries whose duration is less than 10 hours, and the spec doesn't guarantee that the map returned by the `Collectors.groupingBy` methods that take either one or two arguments is mutable.

This is how I'd remove the entries that don't match:

```
public static final long TEN_HOURS_MS = 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

map4.values().removeIf(v -> v < TEN_HOURS_MS);
```

If you want to do everything in a single line, you might want to use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
Map<String, Long> map4 = data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MonitoredData::getActivity, 
            HashMap::new,
            Collectors.summingLong(MonitoredData::getDuration)),
        m -> { m.values().removeIf(v -> v < TEN_HOURS_MS); return m; } ));
```

Here I've used [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to modify the map returned by `Collectors.groupingBy`. And, within the finisher function, I've used [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), which takes a predicate and removes all the entries that match that predicate.

Comment: good job. essentially, I think of `removeOf` last night but I'm not sure, I'm on phone and I can't test. and your ways is more clearly to describe which's duration less than 10 is removed from the map.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? I answer on phone, you need test by yourself.

```
map = map.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(it->TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(it.getValue())>10)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

**OR** using `Collectors#collectingAndThen`:

```
map4 = data.stream()
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(    
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        MonitoredData::getActivity, 
        Collectors.summingLong(MonitoredData::getDuration)
    ),
    r1 -> r1.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(it->TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(it.getValue())>10)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue))
));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you wanted, using
[Google Guava Maps class:](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html)

```
Map<String, Long> map = Maps.filterValues(data.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                    (MonitoredData::getActivity, Collectors.summingLong
                            (MonitoredData::getDuration)
                    )), value -> value > 3);
```

You can obviously write your own method to filter map like that, but since it's already there, on so popular library... How to do it with pure streams: I don't know, but maybe this will be satisfying.

Comment: very neat! Totally forgot you could do that with guava.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code after you got the map:

```
map4.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(a -> a.getValue() > whatever)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```