# How can I create a map of type Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

This is the class `MonitoredData`:

```
class MonitoredData {

    public MonitoredData (DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, String activity){
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public DateTime getStartTime(){
        return this.startTime;
    }
    public DateTime getEndTime(){
        return this.endTime;
    }
    public String getActivity (){
        return this.activity;
    }

}
```

I have a method that returns a list of `MonitoredData`, and I have to generate a data structure of type `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` that contains the activity count for each day of the log.

```
public void activitiesPerDay(List<MonitoredData> monitoredData) {
    Map <Integer, Map<String, Integer>> map = monitoredData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    element -> element.getStartTime().dayOfMonth()),
                    Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)
                    );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java stream filter sum of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101297/java-stream-filter-sum-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a nested `groupingBy` - first by day of month and then by activity:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>> map = 
    monitoredData.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (
                      e -> e.getStartTime().dayOfMonth(),
                      Collectors.groupingBy(MonitoredData::getActivity,
                                            Collectors.counting())));
```

Note that the output type is `Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>>` instead of `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>`, since I'm using `Collectors.counting()`, which returns `Long`.

You can use `Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)` instead of `Collectors.counting()` to obtain an `Integer` count, which will give you the `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` output.

Comment: Thank you! Now, I have to create a data structure of the form Map<String, DateTime> that maps for each activity the total duration computed over the monitoring period and filter the activities with total duration larger than 10 hours